# How to work with two UpdatePanel in single page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My first Update Panel Consist-

```
                        <!--begin twelvecol -->
                        <asp:ScriptManager ID="scrAdmission" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateAdmission" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnApply" EventName="Click" />
                        </Triggers>
                        <ContentTemplate>

                        <div class="twelvecol" style="text-align:center">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddwnCourse" runat="server" style="width:220px;margin-left:-15px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px;padding:2px;font-weight:bold;border:#fff solid 1px;  color:#5c5c5c" onchange="CourseCode();setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;drpcourse\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)">
        <asp:ListItem>Select Course</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>MBA</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>BBA</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>BCA</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>EMBA</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>B.Com</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>MCA</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>PGPM</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>BBM</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>PGDM(1 Year)</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>PGDM(2 Year)</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <div class="twelvecol" style="margin-top:15px;">
         <input class="left-input" type="text" id="txtName" runat="server" required="" name="First Name" placeholder="First Name*" />
    </div>
    <div class="twelvecol">
         <input class="left-input" type="text" id="txtEmail" runat="server" required="" name="Email Id" placeholder="Email Id*" />
    </div>
    <div class="twelvecol">
          <input class="right-input" type="text" id="txtMobile" runat="server" required="" name="Mobile No" placeholder="Mobile No.*" />
     </div>
    <div class="twelvecol">
          <input class="right-input" type="text" id="txtState" runat="server" required="" name="State" placeholder="State*" />
    </div>
    <div class="twelvecol">
         <input class="right-input" type="text" id="txtCity" runat="server" required="" name="City" placeholder="City*" />
    </div>
    <div class="twelvecol">
         <input class="right-input" type="text" id="txtLocation" runat="server" required="" name="Location" placeholder="Location*" />
    </div><br /><br />
    <input id="cbcheck" runat="server" type="checkbox" name="cbcheck" checked="checked" />&nbsp I Agree to the terms of services and privacy policy* <br /><br />
     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblError" Visible="false" ForeColor="#FF5050"></asp:Label>
     <asp:Button CssClass="button_yellow scroll_btn small_btn" Text="Apply Now" runat="server" ID="btnApply" onclick="btnApply_Click" />
</div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My second UpdatePanel Consists Of

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateOrder" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnOrder" EventName="Click" />
                            </Triggers>
                            <ContentTemplate>
                            <div class="sixcol">
                            <form id="contact-form" name="" action="#" method="post">
                            <div class="twelvecol">
                                    <input class="left-input" type="text" name="First Name" placeholder="First Name*" />
                                    <div class="twelvecol">
                                    <input class="right-input" type="text" name="Last Name" placeholder="Last Name*" />
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="twelvecol">
                                    <input class="left-input" type="email" required="" name="Email" placeholder="Email*" />
                                    <input class="right-input" type="text" name="Phone No." placeholder="Phone No.*" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="twelvecol">
                                <input class="full-input" type="text" name="Subject" placeholder="Subject*" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="twelvecol">
                                <textarea name="Message" placeholder="Message..." rows="2" cols="20" class="contact-commnent"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnOrder" runat="server" CssClass="contact-submit button_yellow" Text="Send E-Mail" />
                        </form>                                 
                            </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now problem is this many of the fields have custom required validation in both the forms. when i am trying to click on any of the asp button to submit my fields the other forms validation creates a conflict, how can i use two different update panel in same page but behavior should be different of both the panel.

Answer (score 1):

You may only have one form tag in ASP.NET.   To have the appearance of different forms, you can use the ValidationGroup property each control to create independent sections.

Remove the form element from the second update Panel. Add set the ValidationGroup property to something like contactform.  You don't have to set validationgroup to the top form because an empty string counts as a group.